# Frequent unicast ARP requests

Tags: arp

[Wireshark screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSGUq.png)

I would like to ask if it's considered to be a normal behavior of a router to issue this many (as shown in the screenshot) "refreshing" arp request? As I do not see, for instance, my PC refreshing the entries in the same manner.

Comment: If I'm reading your capture correctly, the router is arping for the same ip address roughly every 3-40 seconds. That doesn't sound normal to me.

Comment: Exactly. I get that the entries sometimes can get refreshed this way but refreshing every few seconds seems really weird to me.